# Short story, where humans encounter an alien race, tell them stories; the aliens act out the stories and kill the researchers

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, soft-sci-fi, first-contact

Can't remember author or title of the story.

Seem to remember the protagonist is an investigator of some sort trying to find out why previously-peaceful alien race has killed the research or liaison team.

Finds out the research team had moved from telling the aliens a peaceful or more self-contained human story (maybe Hamlet?) to Beowulf, and the aliens were acting out the stories.

Comment: I remember either that story, or one that was almost identical. In the one I remember, it was a preacher who told the aliens about Jesus, and the aliens crucified the preacher. Sorry, I can't remember the name though :)

Comment: It sounds like an interesting story.

Comment: @cryptarch: the story you're thinking of is [The Streets of Ashkelon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/138682/story-about-an-logical-alien-race-whose-society-is-destroyed-by-a-missionary-try). That was my first thought but it doesn't really match the description.

Comment: @JohnRennie Thanks! I occasionally think of that story, nice to have a name for it again.

Comment: @cryptarch: it's a great story. I read it when I was a young teen and it made such an impression on me that forty years later I still remember it clearly! :-)

Comment: I have also seen it published as "An Alien Agony".

Comment: I also immediately thought of "The Streets of Ashkelon", but as John Rennie says, it doesn't fit all that well.

Comment: "The Streets of Ashkelon" is great but not the one I'm thinking of. I do seem to remember that darkness played a big factor in the story; maybe the aliens lived in darkness or their home was dark? I still have hopes someone will recognize is! Also @user14111, Hamlet at least doesn't involve mass murders! I think the aliens used themselves to act that one out and the researchers thought it was an internal battle instead of realizing the significance of the story. Beowulf triggered the massacre recreation in the mead-hall. Wish I could remember the title or author!

Comment: Any chance you might have read the January 1983 issue of *Analog*?  There's a story in there "The Vampires Who Loved Beowulf" about a human who has to deal with some aliens who got a little bit too excited when they learned *Beowulf*, although most of the details escape me now.

Comment: DavidW - You might have it! My dad had a straight run of Analog from ~1980 - 1989 and I think I read through most of them. I have some of his collection now but that particular issue doesn't seem to be in the ones I have to positively confirm. Time to start hunting up back issues!

Comment: DavidW had the answer - I was able to get a copy of the issue and read the story; "The Vampires Who Loved Beowulf" was it! The aliens are a dark-dwelling species who recreate their oral histories; the humans offer new stories as trade, among them Beowulf. Humans die in the recreation before the researchers realize what's going on and change which stories they offer. I'd flag David's comment as the answer but someone edited the question and I can't seem to do it now.

Comment: I'm glad Poul Anderson and Gordon Dickson didn't go there with the Hoka stories.

Answer (score 2):

As was established by DavidW, and accepted by RetroGremlin in the comments, "[The Vampires Who Loved Beowulf](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?49391)" by Mary Caraker.

> The aliens are a dark-dwelling species who recreate their oral histories; the humans offer new stories as trade, among them Beowulf. Humans die in the recreation before the researchers realize what's going on and change which stories they offer.

According to [Caraker's entry in *The Encyclopedia of Science Fiction*](https://sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/caraker_mary):

> US author of whom relatively little is known; she is of Finnish descent and began to publish sf when she was nearing 50, with "The Vampires who Loved Beowulf" for Analog in January 1983, a story which makes up part of her first novel, *Seven Worlds* (fixup 1986), whose protagonist, a tough female Space Exploratory Forces agent named Morgan Faraday, is entrusted with the task of improving Communications between humans and other species. Its Young Adult sequel, *The Snows of Jaspre* (1989), places the same protagonist into a political and ecological crisis on the eponymous planet. *Water Song* (1987) and *The Faces of Ceti* (1991), singletons, likewise examine planets in crisis: the first a world, whose surface is almost all water, which faces an Ecological crisis; the second, a planet in dire need of food. *I Remember, I Remember ...* (1991 chap), a novella, recounts the sensations of a woman who awakens on a "coldship" without any memory of how she entered Suspended Animation.